# The value of a array has to become an input field

Tags: jquery, arrays, input, field

this is my array

```
        $m3 = array
          (
           '2' => '2',
           '4' => '4',
           '6' => '6',
           '9' => '9',
           '14' => '14',
           '18' => '18',
           '20' => '20',
           'other' => 'other'

            );
```

How do I get 'other' to change in what I put in the inputfield 'other_interest'?

```
   <?=$form->input('Car/m3', array('name' => "other_interest", 'style' =>        "display:none", 'class' => 'inputText', 'label' => false));?>
```

The jQuery shows the inputfield when I choose other

```
  <script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#CarM3").change(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() === 'other'){ 
            jQuery('input[name=other_interest]').show();   
         } else {
            jQuery('input[name=other_interest]').hide(); 
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That´s the id of the dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that, you want "other" to be displayed in the inputfield : "other_interest".

```
  <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#CarM3").change(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).val() === 'other'){ 
        jQuery('input[name=other_interest]').show();   
        //in the above line, you are just displaying the inputfield
        jQuery('input[name=other_interest]').val("other") //adding this line should do the trick for you!

     } else {
        jQuery('input[name=other_interest]').hide(); 
    }
  });
 });
```

Comment: uhm no haha, When I choose other, I type for example ´test´ and then other will become test in my database

Comment: Ohh! Your question is very unclear...completely misunderstood. "other_interest" is a part of your form, right?

Comment: "other_interest" shows up in my form when i press "other" so I want to put some text in "other_interest" but when I save it. "only other shows up and not the text I wanted.