# How to change my array to a input field

Tags: jquery, arrays

this is my array .

```
$m3 = array
(
'2' => '2',
'4' => '4',
'6' => '6',
'9' => '9',
'14' => '14',
'18' => '18',
'20' => '20',
'other' => 'other'

);
```

now when I choose 'other' a input field will show up.

```
    <?=$form->input('Car/m3', array('name' => "other_interest", 'style' => "display:none", 'class' => 'inputText', 'label' => false));?>
```

this is the script for showing the inputfield

**JQUERY**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#CarM3").change(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val() === 'other') {
            jQuery('input[name=other_interest]').show();
        } else {
            jQuery('input[name=other_interest]').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

What I want is, when I press save that the text in the input field will show up on my page and not 'other'.

Comment: duplicate? [3 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752483/the-value-of-a-array-has-to-become-an-input-field)

Comment: U might want to put more context into your question ... for example; what is $form ?

Comment: So where is the code that decides what shows up on your page?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  $('body').html($('input[name="other_interest"]').val());
});
```